# Don't cover a method in transaction that is running inside a transactional method

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I've asked this question somewhere ,

Suppose i have a method A which is running in transaction by using @transactional ,
if there is a method B  which is being called from that transactional method , by default this will also be running in the same transaction.

So , the question is what to do that B is not covered by the transaction, 
how to avoid the transaction for B.

Comment: method A and B are part of the same class ? or B part of another spring bean , say service.a() calling repository.b() ?

Comment: yeah , it's in the same class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment that both the methods are in the same class (self invocation), following code could work.

```
 @Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired // Self autowiring
    TestService service;

    @Transactional
    public void methodA() {
        service.methodB();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void methodB() {
        //...
    }
}
```

An external call to the `service.methodA()` will initialize a transaction and a self invocation to `service.methodB()` will result in `methodB()` be also part of the same transaction even though it is annotated to not participate in the transaction.
 To work around this we are self-autowiring and calling `methodB()` on that instance. This will result in the transaction configuration for `methodB()` to be honoured.

Following is the reason for self autowiring , [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional.

Reference : [Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED)

> Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one
>   exists. Analogous to EJB transaction attribute of the same name.

Please do read through the doc shared for the limitations with this propagation behavior.
Hope this helps

Comment: yeah , i think this is what i was looking for , what will happen if i just put this '@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED' without self autowiring on methodB ,

Comment: For spring txn management to detect the txn behaviour applied to a method , the call to that method should pass through the proxy. When we call the method directly from another method , the proxy is not involved. To understand this better , please read through [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following pattern to get what you want: Execute A and if B needs the result of A you can send it to be in a nontransactional context.

```
void myFunction() {
        Object result = myTransactionalClass.A();
        B(result);
}
```

Be ware that since you are asking this question (you do not want B() to be transactional), the code mentioned is most definitely gonna work.

Comment: yeah , this could be a way . i thought there may be some annotation kind of thing is there which prevents you to do so .. from the way the person asked this question.